# Using .Net DLL in [R]

Tags: .net, r, dll

I have a C# dll file (developed by a third party, no source code), which I need to run from [R]. I was wondering if you could guide me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to be 100% sure without knowing the details of your .NET component, but the [rClr](https://rclr.codeplex.com/) package might meet your needs.